# Regexp in gawk matches multiples ways

Tags: awk, match

I have some text I need to split up to extract the relevant argument, and my [g]awk match command does not behave - I just want to understand why?! (I have written a less elegant way around it now...).

So the string is `blahblah|msgcontent1=HeaderUUIiewConsenFlagPSMessage|msgtype2=Blah002|msgcontent2=header`

I want to output just the contents of msgcontent1=, so did

`echo "blahblah|msgcontent1=HeaderUUIiewConsenFlagPSMessage|msgtype2=Blah002|msgcontent2=header" | gawk '{ if (match($0,/msgcontent1=(.*)[|]/,a)) { print a[1]; }  }'`

Trouble instead of getting
`HeaderUUIiewConsenFlagPSMessage`

I get the match with everything from there to the last pipe of the string `HeaderUUIiewConsenFlagPSMessage|msgtype2=Blah002`
Now I accept this is because the regexp in `/msgcontent1=(.*)[|]/` can match multiple ways, but HOW do I make it match the way I want it to??

Comment: Did any of the answers below work for you?

Answer (score 5):

With your shown samples please try following. Written and tested in GNU `awk` this will print only contents from `msgcontent1=` till `|` first occurrence.

```
awk 'match($0,/msgcontent1=[^|]*/){print substr($0,RSTART+12,RLENGTH-12)}' Input_file
```

OR with `echo` + `awk` try:

```
echo "blahblah|msgcontent1=HeaderUUIiewConsenFlagPSMessage|msgtype2=Blah002|msgcontent2=header" |
awk 'match($0,/msgcontent1=[^|]*/){print substr($0,RSTART+12,RLENGTH-12)}'
```

---

---

With `FPAT` option in GNU `awk`:

```
awk -v FPAT='msgcontent1=[^|]*' '{sub(/.*=/,"",$1);print $1}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 5):

This is your input:

```sh
s='blahblah|msgcontent1=HeaderUUIiewConsenFlagPSMessage|msgtype2=Blah002|msgcontent2=header'
```

You may use `gnu awk` like this to extract value after `msgcontent1=`:

```sh
awk -F= -v RS='|' '$1 == "msgcontent1" {print $2}' <<< "$s"

HeaderUUIiewConsenFlagPSMessage
```

or using this `sed`:

```sh
sed -E 's/^(.*\|)?msgcontent1=([^|]+).*/\2/' <<< "$s"

HeaderUUIiewConsenFlagPSMessage
```

Or using this `gnu grep`:

```sh
grep -oP '(^|\|)msgcontent1=\K[^|]+' <<< "$s"

HeaderUUIiewConsenFlagPSMessage
```

Answer (score 1):

echo "blahblah|msgcontent1=HeaderUUIiewConsenFlagPSMessage|msgtype2=Blah002|msgcontent2=header" | awk '{ if (match($0,/msgcontent1=([^\|]*)/,a))  print a[1]  }'

this prints HeaderUUIiewConsenFlagPSMessage

The reason your regex match msgcontent1=HeaderUUIiewConsenFlagPSMessage|msgtype2=Blah002 is that matching is 'hungry' so it allways finds the longest possible match

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for how to format data and code in questions and answers.

Answer (score 0):

Also with `awk`:

```
echo 'blahblah|msgcontent1=HeaderUUIiewConsenFlagPSMessage|msgtype2=Blah002|msgcontent2=header' | awk -v FS='[=|]' '$2 == "msgcontent1" {print $3}'
HeaderUUIiewConsenFlagPSMessage
```